# How to insert json data into child table linking with parent table in spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have two classes Student and Address.I am using hibernate as an ORM tool.I have mapped many to one relationship between
student and address like many student can have a same address.My address class is:

```
@Entity
Class Address {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int aid;
private String address;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "sid")
List<Student> students;
//getter and setter,constructor
}
```

My student class is:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int sid;
private String sname;
//getter and setter,constructor
}
```

My controller class for Address class is:

```
public class AddressController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/address",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String insertCategory(@RequestBody Address address) throws        SQLException {
    session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(address);
    return "succesful";
}
```

I insert json data as:
localhost:8080/address

```
{"address":"kathmandu","students":[{"sname":"Pravin"},{"sname":"biplav"}]}
```

But problem is when I want to add student with existing address.I want to insert new student linking with a 
address but without inserting new row in address table.

My controller for address class is :

```
public class StudentController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/student",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String insertCategory(@RequestBody Student student) throws   SQLException {
    session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(student);
    return "succesful";
}
```

I want to insert as :
localhost:8080/student

```
{"sname":"pravin","aid":"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need another REST endpoint to add a Student to an Address. e.g. 
POST http://localhost:8080/address/1/student with the json student request body.

The link you miss is the id of the address you want to update.

---

POST http://localhost:8080/address/1/student

request body: `{"sname":"pravin"}`

```
@POST
@Path("address/{addressId}/student")
public Response addStudentToAddress(@PathParam("addressId") Integer addressId, Student student)) {

   // Fetch address by id
   // Add student to list
   // Save updated address

}
```

As you can see I am using a POST now to 'create' a new student and add it to the existing address entity.

Other options you have are using a PUT to update the address (the whole address object has to be present in the body of the request) or a PATCH where you also can update a resource but only with the fields you pass (you have to write this logic yourself, obviously)

---

PUT http://localhost:8080/address/1

request body: `{"aid":"1","address":"kathmandu","students":[{"sid":"1","sname":"Pravin"},{"sid":"2", "sname":"biplav"}, {"sname":"Nico"}]}`

```
@PUT
@Path("address/{addressId}")
public Response updateAddress(@PathParam("addressId") Integer addressId, Address address)) {

   // match addressId with address body id. throw exception if it does not match
   // Save updated address

}
```

---

PATCH http://localhost:8080/address/1

request body: `{"aid":"1", "students":[{"sid":"1", "sname":"Pravin"},{"sid":"2", "sname":"biplav"}, {"sname":"Nico"}]}`

I do not pass `"address":"katmandu"` in this request body here as I do not want to update this field.

```
@PATCH
@Path("address/{addressId}")
public Response updateAddress(@PathParam("addressId") Integer addressId, Address address)) {

   // match addressId with address body id. throw exception if it does not match
   // merge updated fields
   // Save updated address

}
```

Comment: I didnt get it.Please elaborate

Comment: It does not make sense to update the address resource when pointing to localhost:8080/student. Also, you must pass the address id you want to update because how else you could know which address you should update?